# Recreated UIStepper with 2 UIButtons and a UILabel, Buttons Don't Update as Expected

Tags: swift

I've recreated a UIStepper with 2 UIButtons (increment and decrement) but also with a UILabel (current value output).

It looks like this:

[image]

The functionality should allow the user to decrement by pressing the "-" button until they hit the minValue. When the minValue is reached (in this case it's "1"), the disableIncreaseButton function is called.

The issue is that when "1" is reached, the button is still active. The user would have to press "-" an additional time before the disableIncreaseButton function is called. This also happens when increasing the values as well.

Here's a gif showing the issue:

[image]

I have three corresponding outlets listed below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var decreaseButtonLabel: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var increaseButtonLabel: UIButton!
```

I have a variable that establishes the count (label value) and two constants to establish the min and max values for the "stepper":

```
var count: Int = 8
let minValue: Int = 1
let maxValue: Int = 10
```

I have four functions that enable/disable each of the buttons:

```
func disableDecreaseButton () {
    decreaseButtonLabel.isEnabled = false
    decreaseButtonLabel.alpha = 0.5
}

func enableDecreaseButton () {
    decreaseButtonLabel.isEnabled = true
    decreaseButtonLabel.alpha = 1.0
}

func disableIncreaseButton () {
    increaseButtonLabel.isEnabled = false
    increaseButtonLabel.alpha = 0.5
}

func enableIncreaseButton () {
    increaseButtonLabel.isEnabled = true
    increaseButtonLabel.alpha = 1.0
}
```

I have two IBActions (one controls the decrement and one controls the increment):

```
@IBAction func decreasecount(_ sender: Any) {
   if count == minValue {
        disableDecreaseButton()
        _ = runningCountUpdate (runningCount: runningCount, count: count)
        countLabel.text = "\(count)"
    }
   else if count > minValue && count < maxValue {
        count -= 1
        enableDecreaseButton()
        _ = runningCountUpdate (runningCount: runningCount, count: count)
        countLabel.text = "\(count)"
    }
   else {
        count -= 1
        enableDecreaseButton()
        enableIncreaseButton()
        _ = runningCountUpdate (runningCount: runningCount, count: count)
        countLabel.text = "\(count)"
    }
}

@IBAction func increasecount(_ sender: Any) {
    if count == maxValue {
        disableIncreaseButton()
        _ = runningCountUpdate (runningCount: runningCount, count: count)
        countLabel.text = "\(count)"
    } else if count > minValue && count < maxValue {
        count += 1
        enableIncreaseButton()
        _ = runningCountUpdate (runningCount: runningCount, count: count)
        countLabel.text = "\(count)"
    } else {
        count += 1
        enableIncreaseButton()
        enableDecreaseButton()
        _ = runningCountUpdate (runningCount: runningCount, count: count)
        countLabel.text = "\(count)"
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that the issue is with the following code in my function, but can't seem to isolate why:

```
if count == minValue {
            disableDecreaseButton()
            _ = runningCountUpdate (runningCount: runningCount, count: count)
            countLabel.text = "\(count)"
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines should tell you something:

```
count += 1
enableIncreaseButton()
```

Let's say `count` is 9 when you run that code, `count` is incremented to 10 but then immediately you enable the increase button! When `count` is incremented to 10 the increase button should have been disabled!

You can implement the IBActions this way:

```
// for increase button
count += 1
if count == maxValue {
    disableIncreaseButton()
}
if count != minValue {
    enableDecreaseButton()
}
_ = runningCountUpdate (runningCount: runningCount, count: count)
countLabel.text = "\(count)"

//...

// for decrease button
count -= 1
if count == minValue {
    disableDecreaseButton()
}
if count != maxValue {
    enableIncreaseButton()
}
_ = runningCountUpdate (runningCount: runningCount, count: count)
countLabel.text = "\(count)"
```

The thing to realise here is that pressing the increase button will either disable the increase button or enable the decrease button. It will never enable the increase button, so putting a call to `enableIncreaseButton` there is probably wrong.

Comment: That explains why things were off by just a little. Thank you for explaining what was going on